# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' value

Tags: python

I've written a script to work out the value with variable `program_width`, but I have got a weird error.

The error is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The error are jumping on this line:

```
program_start = 350 + program_width
```

Here is the code I use:

```
if datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30):
   program_width = "250"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.29):
     program_width = "500"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.30) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.45):
     program_width = "750"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.46) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 2):
     program_width = "1000"


if program_width > 1:
   if program_notification:
      button_nofocus = 'channels_bar1.png'
      button_focus = 'channels_yellow.png'
   else:
      button_nofocus = 'channels_bar1.png'
      button_focus = 'channels_yellow.png'

      if program_width < 65:
         program_title = ''
      else:
         program_teststart = 350 + program_width
         print program_teststart = 350 + program_width
```

I'm expecting to add the value with the variable `program_width` to get the return value, example: `350 + 500 = 850`.

Do anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `program_width` to the **string** `"500"` instead of the **int** `500`. Then you're trying to add it to the **int** `350`. These are different types, and the error is telling you exactly what's wrong, you can't add integers and strings.

My guess is that you want it to be an int from the beginning, so

```
program_width = "500"
```

should be

```
program_width = 500
```

But if you really want it to be a string for some reason (you almost certainly don't), you can cast the string into an int with the `int()` function.

```
program_start = 350 + int(program_width)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in all the parts where you're assigning `program_width`:

```
program_width = 250
```

Notice that I removed the `""` surrounding the number. Those quotes mean that the value is a *string*, and you can not add a number to a string, I'm pretty sure that you intended to use `program_width` as an integer. Now this will work:

```
program_teststart = 350 + program_width
```