# python typeerror: an integer is required variable

Tags: python

I'm working on my xbmc media application to create the button control.

I have got a problem with this line:

```
program_controls = xbmcgui.ControlButton(program_start, program_top, program_width, program_height, program_title, focusTexture = button_nofocus, noFocusTexture = button_focus)
```

The error I have got is: TypeError: an integer is required

I found the problem are coming from the variable `program_width` so if i remove them and if i use this:

```
program_controls = xbmcgui.ControlButton(program_start, program_top, 25, program_height, program_title, focusTexture = button_nofocus, noFocusTexture = button_focus)
```

It will work fine without any problem.

Here is the code i use:

```
program_width = 0

if datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30):
   program_width = "250"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.29):
   program_width = "500"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.30) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.45):
   program_width = "750"

elif datetime.timedelta(hours = 1.46) <= program_duration <= datetime.timedelta(hours = 2):
   program_width = "1000"


if program_width > 1:
   if program_notification:
      button_nofocus = 'channels_bar1.png'
      button_focus = 'channels_yellow.png'
   else:
      button_nofocus = 'channels_bar1.png'
      button_focus = 'channels_yellow.png'

   if program_width < 65:
      program_title = ''
   else:
      program_title = title
      program_start = 350 + int(program_width)
      program_height = 38

      program_top = 315 + 37.5 * idx
      if not program_top % 1.0:
         program_top = int(program_top)

         program_controls = xbmcgui.ControlButton(program_start, program_top, program_width, program_height, program_title, focusTexture = button_nofocus, noFocusTexture = button_focus)
```

Do you know how to fix the error for the variable `program_width`??

Comment: Have you checked whether the things that are supposed to be integers actually are integers? In particular, `program_width`?

Comment: @user2357112 yes I actually did. i've got the return value, example: `1060`. I don't understand why i've got an error when everything are working fine. Any idea?

Comment: @user3848630: What type is `"250"`? If you don't know, open up your interactive Python interpreter and write `type("250")` and see whether it's `int` or something else.

Comment: Just change the line `program_width = "250"` to `program_width = 250` (and do the same to the other such lines). Quotes are for strings, not integers.

Comment: @abarnert i don't know as it didnt say anything when i put `type("250")`. should i try `print type("250")`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson can you please post the answer so i can get mark your post as the answer. And can you also please give me upvote as some idiots who have downvote on my question when you understand on my question and you know the answer.

Comment: @user3848630 I posted an answer. I wasn't the downvoter, but I'm guessing the person who did felt you hadn't done enough research to solve the problem on your own, such as determining the type of the variable.

Comment: @user3848630: just to be clear, do you understand how both user2357112 and abarnert were trying to lead you to see what D.R. pointed out, and how you were wrong when you said "yes I actually did"?

Comment: @user3848630: If you put `type("250")` into the interactive Python interpreter, it will respond `str`. If you don't know how to use the interactive interpreter (whether on the terminal, within your favorite IDE, or using an online interpreter), that should be one of the next things you learn.

Comment: @user3848630 It's also worth noting that two hours ago, [you received an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25733709/712603) telling you to do *exactly* this, on the same code. (He followed it by saying `But if you really want it to be a string for some reason (you almost certainly don't)...` before suggesting the current code. But why did you not take his advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines like

```
program_width = "250"
program_width = "500"
```

should be in the form

```
program_width = 250
program_width = 500
```

Using quotes creates a string variable, not an int as you require.