# Why won't my Python Alarm Clock work?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that the user can enter in how many hours and minutes they want it to go off then, it take the local time and the hours and minutes and add the two together to produce the time for the program to go off.

when I run the program I get this error:

```
line 30, in alarm_time   
  alarm_hour = (hour_awake + time.strftime('%H'))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import time

time_now = ''

hour = time.strftime('%H')
minute = time.strftime('%M')

int(hour)
int(minute)


def tick():
    global time_now
    time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print (time_now)


def hours():
    global hour_awake
    hour_awake = int(input("please enter in how many hours you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))
    minutes()

def minutes():
    global minute_awake
    minute_awake = int(input("please enter in how many minutes you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))

def alarm_time():
    alarm_hour = (hour_awake + time.strftime('%H'))
    alarm_minutes = (minute_awake + time.strftime('%M'))
    print (alarm_hour, alarm_minutes)
hours()
alarm_time()
tick()
```

Comment: as a side note.. As you're learning python try to get away from using global variables. They're alright for learning, but make anything larger than short scripts increasingly difficult to manage, and more susceptible to bugs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733681/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str-value)

Comment: Duplicate of same question by same OP https://stackoverflow.com/q/45539185/5411817

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you set `hour_awake` to an int in `def hours():`

```
    hour_awake = int(input(......
```

and the `time.strftime` function returns a `str` (string).  You cannot `+` an `int` and a `str` together.

### EDIT:

To add the number together, you need to `int()` your `str`s:

```
def alarm_time():
    alarm_hour = (hour_awake + int(time.strftime('%H')))
    alarm_minutes = (minute_awake + int(time.strftime('%M')))
    print (alarm_hour, alarm_minutes)
```

Comment: all that does is put together my input and the numbers for the current time as a string. I need it to add the numbers together.

Comment: @CJPeine solution added