# Python Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that the user can enter in how many hours and minutes they want it to go off then, it take the local time and the hours and minutes and add the two together to produce the time for the program to go off.
NOTE: I don't want it to put together my input and the numbers for the current time as a string. I need it to add the numbers together.

When I run the program I get this error:

```
line 30, in alarm_time   
  alarm_hour = (hour_awake + time.strftime('%H'))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import time

time_now = ''

hour = time.strftime("%H")
minute = time.strftime("%M")

str(hour)
str(minute)



def tick():
    global time_now
    time_now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")



def hours():
    global hour_awake
    hour_awake = str(input("please enter in how many hours you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))
    minutes()

def minutes():
    global minute_awake
    minute_awake = str(input("please enter in how many minutes you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))

def alarm_time():
    alarm_hour = (hour_awake + hour)
    alarm_minutes = (minute_awake + minute)
    print (alarm_hour, alarm_minutes)


tick()

hours()
alarm_time()
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733681/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str-value

Comment: I'm not even sure how did you get your error... the code above adds strings and that should 'work' but it will produce rubbish results... on top of that you convert everything to string by calling `str()` and your calls to `str(hour)` do nothing as `hour` is string anyway and then you don't assign value returned by `str()` to anything... you should convert everything to integers by using `int(...)` instead. and delete `str(hour)` and use `hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))` and the same for `minute`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733681/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str-value)

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your question correctly, then try changing your str() to int() instead like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import time

time_now = ''

hour = time.strftime("%H")
minute = time.strftime("%M")

int(hour)
int(minute)



def tick():
    global time_now
    time_now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")



def hours():
    global hour_awake
    hour_awake = int(input("please enter in how many hours you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))
    minutes()

def minutes():
    global minute_awake
    minute_awake = int(input("please enter in how many minutes you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))

def alarm_time():
    alarm_hour = (hour_awake + hour)
    alarm_minutes = (minute_awake + minute)
    print (alarm_hour, alarm_minutes)


tick()

hours()
alarm_time()
```

Comment: you do realize that `int(hour)` does nothing. should have `hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))` instead

Answer (score 0):

`time.strftime('%H')` already is an integer, but
`hour_awake` is a string, by your own definition.
Hence the TypeError.

Python does not perform automatic type conversions. You must do that yourself.   All the operands (variables) must be of the same type to "add":
- Two strings will concatenate into one string,
- two integers will perform arithmetic addition.

You need explicitly cast `hour_awake`  to an integer via: `int(hour_awake)`.
Then you should be able to add them together:

```
alarm_hour = int(hour_awake) + time.strftime('%H')
```

and

```
alarm_minutes = int(minute_awake) + minute
```

This would allow you to keep `hour_awake` and `minute_awake` as strings.
Alternatively, if you do not need them stored as strings, then instead change your `input` line to:

```
hour_awake = int(input("please enter in how many hours you would like to have the alarm go off in. "))
```

.. and do the same for minute_awake.

Comment: I added int to (hour_awake) and the numbers aren't performing arithmetic addition.

Comment: what are you getting: can you print or console.log the two variables you are trying to add together.  Do this on the line just before the line where you attempt to add them.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: remember, that at 60 minutes should turn into 1 hour, and hour "24" should cycle back around to "0" ..you might have to do a bit of math for this, or use the mod `%` operator.

Comment: `print("hour awake:", hour_awake, "time.strftime('%H'):", time.strftime('%H'))`  if you are using python 3.

Comment: 1) did the error message go away ?  2) what values did you get when you printed out the variables before adding them ? - this would be part of the debugging process.

Comment: I added that in and this is what i got:please enter in how many hours you would like to have the alarm go off in. 78
please enter in how many minutes you would like to have the alarm go off in. 78
7823 7837
hour awake: 78 time.strftime('%H'): 23

Comment: notice in the documentation for strftime, that H will be an integer from 00 to 23. So midnight would be 00. 11pm would be 23, and 1am would be 1. etc.

Comment: there is no longer any error message and i entered in 78 for both inputs

Comment: also do `print(alarm_hour = int(hour_awake) + time.strftime('%H'))'.  BTW, why are you entering "78" for the number of hours ?  try something easy like "1" or "3"  78hours is like many Days away!

Comment: i copy and pasted what you wanted me to print and it gave me the same previous error: line 43, in <module>
    print (alarm_hour = int(hour_awake) + time.strftime('%H'))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I suggest you take a break - walk away and return later with fresh eyes, or work on your debugging skills.  Both are part of software development. The answers you need are on this page.

Comment: @CJPeine the other print statement was supposed to read `print(int(hour_awake) + time.strftime('%H'))`. The point was to see how it added the numbers together.  Debugging: `current_hour = time.strftime('%H')` `print("current_hour:", current_hour, "hour_awake:", hour_awake", "sum:", current_hour + hour_awake)`  Now take a look at those values and see if you can make any sense of them.  And, again, why are you inputting "78" hours and "78" minutes ?? Try First testing with Reasonable, easy values.  Are you working on a 24hour clock, or a 12 hour clock?  Anyway, the question you posed is answered